# replace n with the variable while finding the nth child jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this Jquery expression

```
var splitindex = 9;
var mElems = $('#columns div:nth-child(n+9)');
```

Here the '9' is hardcoded,
How to replace 9 with splitindex. 
I wanted to do this for dynamic values of n;

Comment: `$('#columns div:nth-child(n+'+splitindex+')');`

Comment: `var mElems = $('#columns div:nth-child(n+'+splitindex+')');`

Comment: Are you coming from PHP? You may consider this site http://www.basereality.com/PHPToJavascript *for snippet only*

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
$('#columns div:nth-child(n+'+splitindex +')')
```

Comment: Did you notice this part..? `nth-child(n'+splitindex +')` watch carefully..!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#columns div:nth-child(n+"+splitindex+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it just like you append a string `'string'+ val +'remaining'`,

```
var mElems = $('#columns div:nth-child(n+'+ splitindex +')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
var mElems = $('#columns div:nth-child(n+'+splitindex +')');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this:

```
var splitindex = 9;
$("#columns div:nth-child(n+"+splitindex+")");
```